# How to create a shorter name for a type in C#?

Tags: c#

This is my scenario.

```
public Class A
{
  public Class B{..}
.
.
}
```

In a lot of places in my code I have to cast to type B.  The qualified name A.B get really long in my case. For better readability, I want to create a Type variable which holds B type.

```
Type btype = typeof(A.B)
```

My question is how can I use this btype in my casting scenarios. When I try to do

```
   var something = (btype) object
```

I get compile error "Type or Namespace expected".

Comment: you cant do this, look at generics

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use aliasing:

At the top of your code file, in your using statements add this:

```
using SomeShorterName = A.B;
```

Then, everywhere else in that file where you need to refer to A.B, you can use the aliased name.

Comment: You posted seconds before I finished typing. Exactly my suggestion.

Comment: Is there a way to have this at a central location rather than in multiple files?

Comment: @SKG: Yea, I don't think you can, and frankly, I'm glad you can't. Don't want C style typedefs in C#. PIA.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the using directive - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

Use this at the top of any files you want to use.

```
using TypeB = A.B;
```

Answer (score 2):

`Type` is a type of variable that holds information about a type.  The first line is fine but I will explain why the second line is impossible.

the `var` keyword requires that at compile time you know the type of the variable that is going to be stored into it. Also trying to use `bytype` as a casting operator is impossible since it is just a variable.

There is an entire section of the C# language that you need to use: Generics.  This allows dynamic types to be used.  I would suggest making you class generic so you can have compile time compliance.

However as someone has answered, you can use the `using` statement to simplify resolutions.  I was just commenting on the fact you cannot use `Typeof` and `Type` variables to do casting/variables.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error, because btype is a runtime variable, but the compiler needs a compile-time constant in a casting statement.

The only way is this:

> var something = (A.B) object

BTW: If you have to cast very much, it's usually a strong sign that you should reconsider your design.

Thomas

Comment: And of course you can use aliasing to shorten your identifiers, as described in the other answers here...